# How to use calendar in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, calendar, vue.js

I'm using javascript (vue js) and I'm trying to add a calendar that I can choose from it date and time, 
I'm using this one:

```
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
```

but I can only choose date from the calendar,

I want something like the Enabled/Disabled Dates Bootstrap 3 Datepicker v4 Docs, which is this one:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker5'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
                    defaultDate: "11/1/2013",
                    disabledDates: [
                        moment("12/25/2013"),
                        new Date(2013, 11 - 1, 21),
                        "11/22/2013 00:53"
                    ]
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
```

But I can't use it since it uses jQuery and I don't want something with jQuery.
Is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [creating a calendar in javascript / html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42240546/creating-a-calendar-in-javascript-html)

Comment: It seems that vue.js has plugin for this: https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker. See the demo here: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KhQbtTSVuU6r8VCrIdC

Comment: @MoshFeu Yes I'm using this one, but I want to be able to choose the time along with the date in the calendar

Answer (score 0):

You can choose from Material UI. 
http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/date-picker
http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/time-picker

Comment: I tried to run it on jsfiddle to see how it will looks like but it didn't work, is it possible to tell me how? I tried to google it too but they use jQuery

Comment: Read documentation